# Size of array when mapping 2d array to 1d array

Tags: algorithm

If I have a 2d array the way to represent each element in 1 dimension is to use `row_num * row_width + column` if i want the element at row_num, column. But what I'm struggling with is how big should the 1 dimensional array be if I have a 3x3 2d array (just as an example). Shouldn't 3^3 = 9 be enough for the 1d array? But then for element 3,2 the index would be 3 * 3 + 2 = 11. Or should the size be that of the biggest index I want to address - e.g. 3 * 3 + 3 = 12 if I want to address all elements from a 3x3 2d array?

Answer (score 4):

You need to start counting from zero (zero-indexing), where the rows and columns are 0,1,2.

Then element "(3,2)" is really "(2, 1)", or 2*3+1=7, and the final element "(3,3)" is really "(2,2)", which is 2*3+2=8.  This is the last element in the 1-D array, because they're counted from 0 too, so the 9 elements are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

For example:

```
>>> for r in 0,1,2:
...     for c in 0,1,2:
...         print r, c, r*3+c
... 
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
1 2 5
2 0 6
2 1 7
2 2 8
```

Comment: You are correct in case you can start couting from 0 but in my case I'm required to count from 1 so what I did was use (r*N + c) % N

Comment: I don't know how you can be required to count from 1, but you can always simply subtract it off: if r,c = 1,2,3, then you can use `(r-1)*3+(c-1)` instead to get the same indices as above.